Optimize Python Code for Processing Large Historical Betting Data from bz2 Files in a tar Archive
I am working on a project where I need to process a large amount of Betfair historical betting data provided in a tar file. This tar file contains multiple bz2 files, each of which includes a single file with a JSON object per line.
The current approach involves extracting data from these bz2 files, parsing the JSON, and then loading the data into Pandas dataframes for further analysis. I've utilized concurrent.futures for parallel processing and tried to optimize file reading and data handling as much as possible. However, I'm looking for ways to further optimize this process, particularly in terms of reducing the overall processing time and improving memory usage.
Here is the relevant part of the code:
import tarfile
import bz2
import json
import pandas as pd
import io
from concurrent.futures import ProcessPoolExecutor, as_completed
from tqdm import tqdm
import time

def process_bz2_data(bundle):
    market_definition_list = []
    normal_entry_list = []
    for data in bundle:
        with bz2.open(io.BytesIO(data), 'rt', encoding='utf-8') as f:
            for line in f:
                try:
                    json_data = json.loads(line)
                    pt_time = json_data['pt']
                    mc_data = json_data['mc']
                    for info in mc_data:
                        if 'marketDefinition' in info:
                            market_definition_list.append({
                                'market_id': info['id'],
                                'start_datetime': info['marketDefinition']['openDate'],
                                **{f'runner_{i}_id': v['id'] for i, v in enumerate(info['marketDefinition']['runners'])},
                                **{f'runner_{i}_name': v['name'] for i, v in enumerate(info['marketDefinition']['runners'])},
                            })
                        else:
                            market_id = info['id']
                            for change in info['rc']:
                                last_traded_price = change.get('ltp', None)
                                runner_id = change['id']
                                normal_entry_list.append({
                                    'time': pt_time,
                                    'market_id': market_id,
                                    'runner_id': runner_id,
                                    'last_traded_price': last_traded_price
                                })
                except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                    print(f"Error decoding JSON: {e}")
                except UnicodeDecodeError as e:
                    print(f"Error decoding Unicode: {e}")

    return market_definition_list, normal_entry_list

def load_json_to_dataframes(tar_file_path, batch_size=10):
    results = []
    with tarfile.open(tar_file_path, 'r') as tar:
        initial = time.perf_counter()
        files_to_process = [tar.extractfile(member).read() for member in tar.getmembers() if member.isfile() and member.name.endswith('.bz2')] # 41 seconds
        print(f"Elapsed time (Reading Files): {time.perf_counter() - initial:.2f} seconds")
        print(f"We have {len(files_to_process)} files to process.") # 183598

        batches = [files_to_process[i:i + batch_size] for i in range(0, len(files_to_process), batch_size)]

        with ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(process_bz2_data, batch) for batch in batches]

            for future in tqdm(as_completed(futures), total=len(futures), desc="Processing files"): # 3 mins 51 seconds
                result = future.result()
                if result:
                    results.extend(result)

    initial = time.perf_counter()
    market_definitions = [item for result in results[0] for item in result]
    normal_entries = [item for result in results[1] for item in result]
    print(f"Elapsed time (Splitting Data): {time.perf_counter() - initial:.2f} seconds") # 0.00 seconds (does not seem right)

    initial = time.perf_counter()
    market_definition_df = pd.DataFrame(market_definitions)
    normal_entry_df = pd.DataFrame(normal_entries)
    print(f"Elapsed time (Creating DataFrames): {time.perf_counter() - initial:.2f} seconds") # 0.06 secodns (does not seem right)
    # Takes a couple of seconds before displaying the sucess message, not sure why.
    return market_definition_df, normal_entry_df

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tar_file_path = "./data (6).tar"
    market_definition_df, normal_entry_df = load_json_to_dataframes(tar_file_path)
    print('DataFrames loaded successfully.')



If your running this more than once with extra newer data you could preprocess the files, extract them and filter for required data then future loading might be quicker?

@NickSlash I'm currently planning to run this process once for each tar file. I'm using a 600Mb file for testing, and it takes about 5 minutes in total, which is reasonable for my needs. My curiosity is more about pushing the boundaries of performance, akin to the "1 billion row challenge."

[codereview.se] would be better suited for this question.

Before posting on Code Review please read A guide to Code Review for Stack Overflow users and How do I ask a good question? first.
